# How i can make Jquery Accordion Plugin work in IE7?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the JQuery UI Accordion Plugin in my website, linking the version 1.10.3 of JQuery and it works fine in Chrome 31, Firefox 26.0 and IE 11, but i can't find out how make to it work in IE7.

I did check many times that the file is correctly linked

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and the needed jquery code is  in the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('div.accordion').accordion({
            heightStyle: "content"
            //collapsible: false,
            //active: 0 
        });

    });
    </script>
```

, also tried changing the version of JQuery but doesn't work.

Debuggin with the IE Developers Tools always get this error  "Object doesn't support this property or method "accordion" ".

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with the IE 7, you have to set "animated : false" and "autoHeight : false" to fix it.

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $('div.accordion').accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            animated : false,
            autoHeight : false
        });

    });
```

Comment: Check this link http://www.dreamdealer.nl/articles/jquery_accordion_object_doesnt_support_this_property_or_method_error_in_ie.html